# PHP backslash escaping

Tags: php, escaping, quotes, backslash

```
$backslash = '\\\\';
echo $backslash.$backslash;
```

would print two backslashes, while I'd expect it to print four.

Also,

```
$backslash = '\\';
echo $backslash.$backslash;
```

would only print one.

Why is that?

---

**EDIT:**
Sorry for wasting your time.
The problem was I didn't actually `echo` it but instead returned the stored the value in a variable `$escaped`, which I then did other stuff with that actually caused the problem.

Comment: do you get the same output when using `" "`?

Comment: Yes, I do. It's weird.

Comment: What's the php version?

Comment: Unable to reproduce, http://codepad.org/0KHqxYCC. Must be some server/php config

Comment: Also [unable to reproduce](https://eval.in/94857) on 5.4.6, 5.5.1

Comment: Unable to reproduce as well! Just run it without any `require/include` on your page and see what you got?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's as expected. `'`-quoted strings have only two meta-characters which need to be escaped within them: `'` and `\`. The `'` has to be escaped, or you'd terminate the string early, and since `\` itself is the escape character, it has to be escaped as well.

e.g.

```
<?php
$foo = '\\\';
echo $foo;
```

when executed will produce:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE in test.php on line 3
```

because the first two `\` escape each other, becoming a single literal `\` inside the string, and the 3rd `\` escapes the `'`, causing the string to run off the end of the line and make the `echo $foo` **PART** of the string.

I cannot reproduce your second example. `$foo = '\\';` will assign a SINGLE backslash to the string, and since you're printing out the variable twice, SHOULD get `\\` as your output.

---

followup: with this code:

```
$two_slashes = '\\';
$four_slashes = '\\\\';
echo $two_slashes . $two_slashes . "\n";
echo $four_slashes . $four_slashes . "\n";
```

I get:

```
\\
\\\\
```

as output, as expected. This is on PHP 5.3.3 (Redhat enterprise 65.3)

Comment: Yes, but that's why I expect '\\\\' to be TWO backslashes, hence when I echo it twice to get 4.

Comment: @Jenox I get TWO when echo `'\\\\'`! You must check for http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php and turn them off!

Comment: Magic quotes: This feature has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP 5.4.0.

Comment: I know.. But my server returns everything as expected.. 4 backslashes turn into 2. Everything is correct!?

Comment: Was totally my bad, check my edit. Thanks for your time though.

Answer (score 0):

```
$backslash = '\\\\';
echo $backslash.$backslash;
```

output = \\\\

```
$backslash = '\\';
echo $backslash.$backslash;
```

output=\\

what's the problem?

Comment: I do not get this output, that's the problem Sherlock. Read my question please.